# Rolling compounded average growth rate coding pine script in tradingview

Tags: arrays, loops, rate

Want to code pine script of rolling compounded average growth rate of sales/revenue of 3 years and plot in table format in trading view. please guide I want to use pine script code in tradingview.....and this final growth rate I wanted to use in another equation .please guide